# WSClient soap client in grails/groovy

Tags: grails, soap, groovy, cxf

I have a few problems with the cxf + WSClient in soap.

I am writing a small tool in grails that must make SOAP calls to an existing service.

WSClient (groovyws-0.5.3-20100521.062225-1.jar) seemed like the perfect solution to my problem. 
However when i tried to implement a call to one of the actions i get two problems.

**Problem #1 NullPointerException when making a call to some of the actions.**

I have tracked down the code that is throwing the exception inside of

```
AbstractCXFWSClient.invokeMethod(String methodName, Object args)

     if (!operationToBeInvoked.isUnwrapped()){
                //Operation uses document literal wrapped style.
                inputMessageInfo = operationToBeInvoked.getWrappedOperation().getInput();
     } else {
                inputMessageInfo = operationToBeInvoked.getUnwrappedOperation().getInput();
            }
```

specifically `operationToBeInvoked.getWrappedOperation()` I have isolated the code in a unit test and find that both `operationToBeInvoked.getWrappedOperation()`  and `operationToBeInvoked.getWrappedOperation()` result in null objects.  I have tried to figure out what is causing it however i think i have gotten to the end of my knowledge.

**Problem #2 WSClient.create(String classname) is eating a ClassNotFoundException (and then throwing a NullPointerException)**

Basicly when I make the following call

```
def event = client.create("com.mypackage.MyBean");
```

Same bean that i can see by browsing the services from the browser.

```
<xs:complexType name="myBean">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="facets" nillable="true" type="tns:beanBean"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sortId" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="itemId" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="preview" type="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I get a NPE.  When i drill down to figure out why i get an NPE, I find that its because the classloader on the WSClient can't find "com.mypackage.MyBean" eats the ClassNotFoundException  and then inevitably throws an NPE.

Edit: Should I be using a different client the WSClient/cxf ?  I really wanted to avoid having to roll my own.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicly I didn't find the answer.  I basicly was forced to uninstall the two plugins and cxf  and not using the groovy WSClient.

What i did was install the ws-client plugin for grails and that worked.

http://www.grails.org/plugin/ws-client

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the jaxen's jar in .grails lib cxf plugin folder in your project.  It should solve your problem.